# Turning list objects into list names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have part of a python script that has become redundant and I want to use a for statement to consolidate it. Along with that, I want to make "List" as a list of all the list names that lead to making the lists I want (I hope that makes sense).

My current code looks like this...

```
List = ['List1', 'List2', 'List3']

#List1 List
info_parsed = info.loc[info['Group'].isin(['List1'])]
List1 = info_parsed['Name'].to_list()

#List2 List
info_parsed = info.loc[info['Group'].isin(['List2'])]
List2 = info_parsed['Name'].to_list()

#List3 List
info_parsed = info.loc[info['Group'].isin(['List3'])]
List3 = info_parsed['Name'].to_list()
```

Is there a way to make this shorter?

Any advice is truly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of creating variables dynamically it is usually better to create a dictionary with names as keys and use it like: `List['List1'] = info_parsed['Name'].to_list()`

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
list_names = ['List1', 'List2', 'List3']

for name in list_names:
    info_parsed = info.loc[info['Group'].isin([name])]
    globals()[name] = info_parsed['Name'].to_list()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
List = ['List1', 'List2', 'List3']
Lists = [info.loc[info['Group'].isin([l])]['Name'].to_list() for l in List]
```

Answer (score 0):

`map(function, list)`

```
map(lambda x: info.loc[info[''Group].isin([x])]['Name'].to_list(), List)
```

actually you can write the function like:

```
def f(x):
   I = info.loc[info[''Group].isin([x])]
   if I is None: return None
   L = I['Name'].to_list()
   return L

map(f, List)
```